# kendoui grid is not showing data?

Tags: php, codeigniter, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i have used kendoui grid in my codeigniter web application.

The grid is showingup, but there no data loaded in that.

Here is the details of what i have done.

i have used the query and did echoed it in file in json encode
The output of echo is.

```
{"data":[{"Username":"admin","FirstName":"System","MiddleNames":"Default","LastName":"Administrator","City":"Sakhakot","Email":"kifayat@zorkif.com"},{"Username":"guest","FirstName":"System","MiddleNames":"Default","LastName":"Guest","City":"Peshawar","Email":"kifayat@zorkif.com"}]}
```

the location of this data file in which i have done the above echo. is

```
http://localhost:12/projects/zorkif_nextgen/user_management/manage_users/list_view/
```

here is my view file in which i want to show the grid.

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by JetBrains PhpStorm.
 * User: Kill3rCoder-Lapi
 * Date: 3/21/13
 * Time: 10:58 AM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */

?>
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource:{
                read: {
                    read: "<?php echo base_url() ?>/index.php/user_management/manage_users/list_view/"
                },
                schema:{
                    data: "data"
                }
            },
            columns: [
                { field: "Username",
                  title:"Username"
                },
                { field: "FirstName",
                  title:"First Name"
                },
                {field:"MiddleNames"},
                {field:"LastName"},
                {field:"City"},
                {field:"Email"}
     ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my Head Section for of my application.

```
        <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Zorkif Business One Next Generation</title>

        <link href="<?php echo base_url('kendo_ui/styles/kendo.common.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="<?php echo base_url('kendo_ui/styles/kendo.default.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="<?php echo base_url('kendo_ui/js/kendo.web.min.js'); ?>"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url('kendo_ui/js/kendo.grid.min.js'); ?>"></script>





    <link href="<?php echo base_url('styles/zorkif_fluid_main.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--  Designed By Zorkif.com Team  -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('styles/messages.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--  The main message boxes appearing on the top of the page  -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('styles/header.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--  To style the header of the page  -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('styles/tab_bar.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--  To style the Tabs Menu and the Title Section of the page  -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('styles/action_buttons.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--  To style the action buttons and search box of the page  -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('styles/footer.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--  To style the header of the page  -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('styles/zorkif_slider.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--  To style the header of the page  -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('styles/login_form.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--  To style the header of the page  -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('styles/forms.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--  To style the form elements in the  page  -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('styles/tables.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--  To style the default tables and data view and data entry tables in page  -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('styles/tiles_cpanel.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--  To style the information Tiles tabs for the cpanel  -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('styles/page_columns.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--  The file is used to privide column based division of the page design  -->


    <script src="<?php echo base_url('scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php /*base_url('scripts/cssrefreshNONE.js'); */?>"></script><!-- for Develoment Perpose Only and must be removed in the production version -->
    -->
    <!-- Start of Accordion Menu -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('scripts/horz_accordion_menu/accordion_menu.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('scripts/horz_accordion_menu/accordion_menu.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- End of Accordion Menu -->

    <!--  Nivo Image Slider -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('scripts/nivo-slider/themes/default/default.css'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('scripts/nivo-slider/nivo-slider.css'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <!-- End of Image Slider -->

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo base_url('favicon.ico'); ?>" />


    <!-- Kendo UI Start  -->
        <!-- Kendo UI Web styles -->
        <link href="<?php echo base_url('kendo_ui/styles/kendo.common.min.css'); ?>" type="text/css"  />
        <link href="<?php echo base_url('kendo_ui/styles/kendo.default.min.css'); ?>" type="text/css"  />

        <!-- Kendo UI Web scripts -->
        <script src="<?php echo base_url('kendo_ui/js/jquery.min.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url('kendo_ui/js/kendo.web.min.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

So now i cant figure out where is it i am stuck???

anyone with Kendoui expertise??

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
read: {
    read: ...
}
```

when it should be:

```
transport: {
    read: ...
}
```

By the way, did you realize that are including KendoUI twice? also, the first time that you include it you include Kendo not having include jQuery before. I don't think that that will work

Comment: Many many thanks for replying in desprate times.
i fixed my error from read to transport, Plus i did also removed the second kendo.web.min.js from bottom of head section.

But still the data is not showing up?
What to do? Why it is giving this error?

Comment: Is your grid been formatted (styled)? Is only data what is not showing up?

Comment: Actually what you should remove are the top 4 lines of the head since there the order of the JavaScripts is not correct.

Comment: Yes sir, grid is formatted correctly.
Only data is not showing up :(

Comment: I've just realized that you say that data is in `http://localhost:12/projects/zorkif_nextgen/user_management/manage_users/list_view/
` but then you use `/index.php/user_management/manage_users/list_view/`. Just in case `index.php` is not doing correctly the mapping of urls, would mind trying directly the url or in your browser open the source file and check what is actually generating as read URL.

Comment: sir, it works with both index.php and without index.php, i have used .htacess to bypass index.php but both of them link is working fine.
i also now viewed the same file with this code.
http://localhost:12/projects/zorkif_nextgen/index.php/user_management/manage_users/list_view/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26620/discussion-between-syed-haider-hassan-and-onabai)